# Android Emma code coverage integration with Hudson

Tags: android, hudson, code-coverage, emma

I am trying to create Emma coverage reports in Android test project and to integrate those with Hudson/Sonar. I am succeeded in creating coverage files like coverage.xml,coverage.html,coverage.txt,coverage.em,coverage.ec etc by creating and running ant builds through command prompt in local system. I am able to view 91% of code coverage in coverage.html file with one-by-one details about all classes and packages.But I need to include these in Hudson.
How I can integrate these with Hudson? How I can show code coverage and No of successful tests in Sonar?

Reffered pages :
[Building an Android app and test project](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+an+Android+app+and+test+project) &
[EMMA Code coverage and JUnit](http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg51344.html)

Comment: http://blog.questmaster.de/index.php/2012/07/24/android-unit-tests-and-coverage-in-sonar/. This page giving some more info on Sonar integration